# class lombok.javac.apt.LombokProcessor (in unnamed module) cannot access class com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment

Tags: java, lombok

Buena tarde soy nuevo en Java y microservicios, estoy levantando un microservicio gateway y mi arroja el siguiente error

> class lombok.javac.apt.LombokProcessor (in unnamed module @0xe38f0b7) cannot access class com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment (in module jdk.compiler) because module jdk.compiler does not export com.sun.tools.javac.processing to unnamed module @0xe38f0b7

### Intentos

ya intente cambiando el jdk y la version de lombok en mi proyecto pero nada, creo que es algo de compatibilidad pero no se bien, agradezco su ayuda.

## Detalles adicionales

este es mi pom.xml

[image: captura del archivo pom.xml]

Comment: sube la versión a 1.18.22 que ya es compatible con java 16

Comment: gracias @RuslanLópez si era eso!!!!!!

Comment: Por favor pon el código como texto.

Answer (score 1):

He notado dos cosas en base a tu captura del código.

1. La versión de java es la 16
2. La clase en que te da error `LombokProcessor` es una que se usa cuando se especifica a lombok como procesador de anotaciones
3. en tu caso lombok se usa como procesador de anotaciones desde el plugin [maven-compiler-plugin](/questions/tagged/maven-compiler-plugin)
4. La versión de Lombok especificada es la 1.18.20

En el github de lombok normalmente hallas cuando las versiones son incompatibles, buscando un poco hallarás [acerca de la version 16](https://github.com/projectlombok/lombok/issues/2681).

Allí te especifica que debes de usar la versión `1.18.22` en la que ya solucionan los problemas de compatibilidad

Answer (score 1):

Tuve ese problema lo solucione en maven solo debes colocar que se ejecute lombok primero antes de mapstruct. en annotationProcessors

```
<properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
        <org.mapstruct.version>1.5.5.Final</org.mapstruct.version>
        <org.projectlombok.version>1.18.28</org.projectlombok.version>
        <org.lombok-mapstruct-binding>0.2.0</org.lombok-mapstruct-binding>
    </properties>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>17</source>
                    <target>17</target>
                    <annotationProcessors>
                        <annotationProcessor>lombok.launch.AnnotationProcessorHider$AnnotationProcessor</annotationProcessor>
                        <annotationProcessor>org.mapstruct.ap.MappingProcessor</annotationProcessor>
                    </annotationProcessors>
                    <annotationProcessorPaths>
                        <path>
                            <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
                            <artifactId>mapstruct-processor</artifactId>
                            <version>${org.mapstruct.version}</version>
                        </path>
                        <path>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                            <version>${org.projectlombok.version}</version>
                        </path>

                        <path>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok-mapstruct-binding</artifactId>
                            <version>${org.lombok-mapstruct-binding}</version>
                        </path>
                    </annotationProcessorPaths>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
     </plugins>
</build>
```